# Querying mysql workbench for specific attribute

Tags: mysql

in mysql workbench, I want to run:

```
SELECT * FROM testdatabase.testTable;
```

But I want to restrict this to entries in the table that only have a specific attribute value, like "userId"=123

How would I do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a [`WHERE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause:

```
SELECT * FROM testdatabase.testTable WHERE userId = 123;
```

This will select all rows from your table that have the `userId` 123.

Comment: Okay, so once I type that in to the box in mysql workbench, how do I get it to run that? It doesn't change the results grid.

Comment: There should be an *execute* button in the toolbar. As far as I remember, it had a flash icon on it.

Comment: Alright, and why does the answer have SELECT "*" instead of just SELECT...I'm used to unix, where the * means all...why does the "all" need to be specified here? Thank you

Comment: Have a look at the docs for `SELECT` I linked in my answer. The `*` indicates that all *columns* should be selected, not all *rows*.